# Unable to debug apache cordova apps

Tags: android, apache, cordova, android-sdk-tools

I am able to debug with the latest android devices version, but not with older versions.

```
Unable to debug Apache Cordova apps on Android targets in the Release or Distribution configurations or on targets running versions <4.4. See Output window for JavaScript console output
```

Your suggestions please...

Comment: you can look into weinre

Comment: @jcesarmobile `weinre`  sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

If your Android version is lower than 4.4 your app doesn't use Chrome Webview for web apps, but the older WebView which doesn't have debug abilities. You can debug web app with Android 4.4+ as specified [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging).

For old Android devices the good new is [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org) which ships the Chrome WebView into your device, as they write it:

> Enable the most advanced web innovations with the Crosswalk Project
>   web runtime to develop powerful Android and Cordova apps.

With that new WebView you also can [debug](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started/remote_debugging.html) your app. If you integrate your Cordova app with Crosswalk it's real simple, tried it myself just now.

It's also a good practice to use Crosswalk for old devices. Many browser API's been extended and changed with the new WebView, Crosswalk saves you much pain of backward compatibility.

Comment: I have an android device that is above 4.4 and i was getting the same error. check out below my answer which fixes the deployment issue and the error in VS 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It turns out that if you have a previous release build on your phone you won't be able to deploy a debug build until you uninstall the release build and then the VS debug deployment  starts working!.